# how can I get value in SimpleXMLElement object

Tags: php, xml

Thanx for reading. I have an *simplexmlElement* object. I get this result:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [item] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [key] => memberCard [value] => memberCard ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [key] => AuthToken [value] => Auth-Token ) ) )
```

when I use this code:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file('get.xml');
print_r($xml->clientSide[0]->item);
```

Now I'm trying to get key value but I can't, I tried

`print_r($xml->clientSide[0]->item[0]->item[0]->key);`

but the result was:

`SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => memberCard )`

I don't know how to get key node value.
The original xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:mapping xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:IM-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <serverSide xsi:type="IM-ENC:Array"></serverSide>
    <clientSide xsi:type="IM-ENC:Array">
        <item xsi:type="ns2:Map">
            <item>
                <key xsi:type="xs:string">memberCard</key>
                <value xsi:type="xs:string">memberCard</value>
            </item>
            <item>
                <key xsi:type="xs:string">AuthToken</key>
                <value xsi:type="xs:string">Auth-Token</value>
            </item>
        </item>
    </clientSide>
</xs:mapping>
```

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @rramiii, Are you trying to get all the key value pairs ?

Comment: Yes next step is to get all key value pairs :)

Comment: You can accept hindmost answer , as he gave you the clue :) I have put up my answer on how to loop through. Also, check the demo attached.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do explicit conversion to `string`:

```
print_r((string)$xml->clientSide[0]->item[0]->item[0]->key);
```

Thereby you call the method [`SimpleXMLElement::__toString`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.tostring.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `foreach` to loop over all the key-value pairs..

```
foreach ($xml->clientSide->item->item as $k=>$child)
{
    echo $child->key;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $child->value;
    echo "<br><br>";
}
```

[<kbd>Working Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/136191)